# Отсутствуют вкладки design/text редактора Intellij Idea

Tags: android, intellij-idea

Собственно, пропали кнопки переключения режимов Design/Text в редакторе layout-файлов, поэтому редактировать визуально активность невозможно. 
Переустанавливал Intellij Idea - без изменений.
[image: скриншот 1]
[image: скриншот 2]

О каких кнопках/вкладках речь:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Получилось как-то решить? Возникла та же проблема и переключение темы не помогло.

Comment: Насколько я помню, помогла только полная переустановка.

Answer (score 0):

Немножко не понял о каких режимах идет речь, но переустановкой проблему не решишь - настройки программы нужно править/очищать. Папка с настройками называется `.IdeaIC2017.1` ну или как-то так в зависимости от версии.. Лежит в директории `C:\Users\{username}\.IdeaIC2017.1` если вы в windows работаете.

Comment: Настройки сносил тоже, естественно. Похоже, дело в самом проекте.

Comment: Добавил скриншот тех самых кнопок, которые есть в другом проекте.

Comment: Почему-то не могу увидеть Ваши скриншоты. Но если вкладок нет, то файл не определяется как андроид-лэйаут. Или Вы не то открыли, или настройки проекта не правильные. Проект вообще собирается, запускается?

Comment: Конечно же собирается и запускается. Сносить .idea не вариант, т.к. зависимостей в проекте много (non-Gradle).

Comment: Если проект без gradle, то не все возможности могут быть задействованы, хотя сказать наверняка про gesign не могу. Ещё есть вариант, что файл открывается не в том редакторе